# Dynamically generated div isn't attaching my event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a modal plugin but for some reason one of the divs that I generate isn't getting a click event listener that I am attaching to it.

`<a class="close" id="js-close-modal"></a>` is what I'm referring to. I'm using jQuery's on, but that doesn't seem to help.

```
        var $caller = $(this);
        var $modal = $('.modal');

        $caller.on('click', $caller, function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();

            $('#js-close-modal').on('click', $('#js-close-modal'), function(e) {
                $('.modal_outer').remove();
                $('#modal_page_cover').remove();
            });


            var modal_outer = $('<div />');
            modal_outer.addClass('modal_outer');
            modal_outer.css({
                top: ($(window).scrollTop()) + 'px'
            });

            var $div = $('<div />');

            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass('modal');

            var modal_inner = $('<div />');
            modal_inner.addClass('modal_inner');

            modal.append(modal_inner);
            modal_outer.append(modal);

            var body = $('body');
            body.append(modal_outer).hide().fadeIn(100);
            modal_inner.text('yo');

            var close = $('<a />');
            close.addClass('close').attr('id', 'js-close-modal');
            close.insertBefore(modal_inner);


            var page_cover = $('<div />');
            page_cover.attr('id', 'modal_page_cover');
            body.prepend(page_cover);

});
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/someprimetime/P5B4q/19/)

Any idea why?

Comment: If you use `on` method in `"live"` way, you should add event to one of the parents of the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing a jQuery object in as your selector on the `$.on` method. You should instead be passing in a *selector* alone:

```
$("body").on("click", "#js-close-modal", function(){
  /* Do stuff */
});
```

You made the same error on `$caller.on()`. You don't bind `$.on()` to the element you're clicking, you bind it to one of the parents of that element. I've bound the even to the `body` element, but you should ideally bind it to a much closer parent.

Making the change I demonstrated above fixes your close button: http://jsfiddle.net/P5B4q/22/

Of course you're creating the close button in the same code, so event delegation isn't really necessary. You could do away with the code above, and modify your close button upon creation:

```
var close = $('<a />');
close.addClass('close').attr('id', 'js-close-modal');
close.insertBefore(modal_inner);
```

Replace that with:

```
$("<a>", { class: "close", id: "js-close-modal" })
  .on("click", function(){ $('#modal_page_cover, #modal_outer').remove() })
  .insertBefore( modal_inner );
```

Comment: this is by far the best way to do it. Using event bubbling is always an efficient, sure fire way to work with dynamic content and listeners.

Comment: @bmarti44 I don't think it's necessarily the best way to do it *by far*.  It certainly has its advantages for some dynamic content, but in a self-contained set of elements that are created and destroyed in a bundle you will get a slight performance boost by binding to the dynamically created elements themselves.  This also makes it easier to unbind from those elements and it gives you more control.  I wouldn't knock the delegation method of `.on`, though.

Comment: Didn't know you could just chain the event at the time of creation. That's rad. Thanks.

Comment: @bob_cobb jQuery is very, very rad ;)

Answer (score 1):

You bind the click event to `#js-close-modal` before it's appended to the DOM.  That is to say, `$("#js-close-modal")` is not selecting anything.  You need to bind it *after* you've appended it (i.e. after `close.insertBefore`.  You can also chain it at that time, and by the way you can chain the other calls too (the element creation, `attr`, `insertBefore` ...)

In an unrelated suggestion, you should try to limit the amount of code you post to the relevant points.  Giant code walls tend to scare people away.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of binding, the `$('#js-close-modal').size()` returns 0. This is because the element is not created yet. Re-arrange your code and it should work. [Here is the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P5B4q/21/)

And here is the what have changed:

```
(function($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            var settings = $.extend({
                'fade': false
            }, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                var $caller = $(this);
                var $modal = $('.modal');

                $caller.on('click', $caller, function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $('body').on('click', function(e) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        var modalCover = $('.modal_outer');
                        if (modalCover.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                            $('.modal_outer').remove();
                            $('#modal_page_cover').remove();

                        }
                    });

                    /*$('#js-close-modal').on('click', $('#js-close-modal'), function(e) {
                            $('.modal_outer').remove();
                            $('#modal_page_cover').remove();
                    });*/ //moved down

                    $('body').keyup(function(e) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                            $('.modal_outer').remove();
                            $('#modal_page_cover').remove();
                        }
                    });




                    var modal_outer = $('<div />');
                    modal_outer.addClass('modal_outer');
                    modal_outer.css({
                        top: ($(window).scrollTop()) + 'px'
                    });

                    var $div = $('<div />');

                    var modal = $('<div />');
                    modal.addClass('modal');

                    var modal_inner = $('<div />');
                    modal_inner.addClass('modal_inner');

                    modal.append(modal_inner);
                    modal_outer.append(modal);

                    var body = $('body');
                    body.append(modal_outer).hide().fadeIn(100);
                    modal_inner.text('yo');

                    var close = $('<a />');
                    close.addClass('close').attr('id', 'js-close-modal');
                    close.insertBefore(modal_inner);
                    //moved from above.
                    $('#js-close-modal').on('click', $('#js-close-modal'), function(e) {
                            $('.modal_outer').remove();
                            $('#modal_page_cover').remove();
                    });



                    var page_cover = $('<div />');
                    page_cover.attr('id', 'modal_page_cover');
                    body.prepend(page_cover);
                });


            });

        }
    };

    $.fn.modal = function(method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);

$(window).ready(function() {
    $('.js-modal').modal({
        'fade': false
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-querying for the element, you can just bind the click handler to the newly created element. http://jsfiddle.net/P5B4q/20/

```
close.on('click', function(e) {
    $('.modal_outer').remove();
    $('#modal_page_cover').remove();
});
```